# How to give arguments after Here Document?

Tags: python, bash, heredoc

I want to execute a python script via “Here Document” following some arguments in my bash shell script, as follows

```
python <<'__SCRIPT__'
...
__SCRIPT__
ARG1 ARG2 ...
```

But don't know how to give these arguments. I have tried putting them following python, following **SCRIPT** and a new line right after **SCRIPT**. But errors are reported in all of the cases when executed.

So what is the right way?

BR, RUOCHEN

Answer (score 9):

The arguments are part of the command.

```
python - arg1 arg2 << ...
```

Comment: This solution is to give the arguments to python. But what I really want is to give the arguments to the "script".

Comment: ... What did you think Python gave the arguments to?

Comment: Your solution looks like: python arg1 arg2 ... SCRIPT
Arguments go to python and SCRIPT gets nothing
What I expect is: python SCRIPT arg1 arg2 ... (simply identical to <path>/SCRIPT arg1 arg2)
Arguments go to SCRIPT and python gets nothing

Comment: Oh, I have omitted the '-' before ARGS. So much thanks to you all.

Answer (score 5):

`<<__SCRIPT__` is not actually a script passed to python, it's a stream containing the script. You have to tell python where to get the script, which is `-` in this case. That's why `python - arg1 arg2 <<'__SCRIPT__'`:

```
$ cat here-py.sh
python - foo bar <<__SCRIPT__
import sys
print(sys.argv)
__SCRIPT__
$ ./here-py.sh
['-', 'foo', 'bar']
```